# django using variable in request.POST.get('x')

Tags: html, django

In my current project, users can create spreadsheets with fields, then each field inherits a unique ID based on the column it is attached to in the spreadsheet, so when fields are updated, my template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="{{field.unique_id}}" id="{{field.unique_id}}" value="{{field.data}}">
```

But in my views, when I attempt to grab the value from the field:

```
request.POST.get('field.unique_id')
```

It sees nothing because it's looking for literally 'field.unique_id' and not the variable that field.unique_id would produce.

Is there a way to tell it to replace field.unique_id with the variable or do I have to define the id of the POST get manually?

Comment: Have you tried `request.POST.get(field.unique_id)`?

Comment: Gives me the same issue, doesn't see a field at all and updates it to be blank

Comment: If you print `request.POST`, is the key there?

Comment: no, GET:<QueryDict: {}>. It doesn't see anything inside the GET field

Comment: That's `GET`, what about `POST`. Please show the template that contains the form.

Comment: POST:<QueryDict: {u'1': [u'30-1'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'e4sc2NmFbzRjMJDkQxKdoMapi4cODkHl'], u'submit': [u'Update Field']}>, My post data contains it but the view isn't reading it because it's asking for the wrong thing

Comment: What is the value of `field.unique_id`? The integer `1`? In that case, you'll need to do `request.POST.get(str(field.unique_id))`

Comment: Ah that did it, thank you! I didn't know about using str() to force it to convert the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable in request.POST.get() instead of a string, for example.

```
request.POST.get(my_var)
```

However in your case, `request.POST.get(field.unique_id)` does not work, since the keys in `request.POST` are strings, and `field.unique_id` is an integer.

The answer is to use `str()` to convert it to a string.

```
request.POST.get(str(field.unique_id))
```